# Error in importing Photos to app album

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to request image.
[image]

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result: UIImage!, info: NSDictionary!) in
        cell.setThumbnailImage(result)
```

In this NSDictionary is not identical to the given format. What to use instead of that?

Comment: Did you try `result: [NSObject : AnyObject]!`, as indicated by the error message (and the documentation) ?

Comment: If this is solved, either post an answer (either you or Martin) and then accept it, or just delete this question. In this case, the latter is probably fine.